# How to I redirect to another page *after* printing document?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an event called `SubmitResponse()`.

A user is presented with a list of questions and possible responses.  After completing the responses, the user clicks the Preview button.  If responses are correct, the user clicks the SubmitResponse button and then `SubmitResponse()` processes it.

Upon clicking the SubmitResponse button, a print screen pops up for the user to print a copy.  This is the calling code for the JS print feature.

```
finsub.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "print_form()")
```

Works fine but there is one problem.  We would like the user to be redirected to the screen that displays results of his/her response with the code below.

```
Response.Redirect("results.aspx")
```

What is happening is that once the user clicks the submitResponses button, s/he is immediately redirected to the `results.aspx page` and the print feature is no longer available.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You could create a landing page that simply performs the print with a META-refresh set for some time in the future (assumed printing went well) that executes.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I tried it before even posting here. It didn't work. Actualy, it work partially in that it would redirect me but for some reason, it would first open the form page, thereby exposing it for duplicate entry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the printing and redirect all via javascript.  Here is an example that should work:

```
function doPrint() {
    window.print();            
    document.location.href = "Somewhere.aspx"; 
}
```

Link it to a `Button`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print"
    OnClientClick="doPrint(); return false;" />
```

Comment: Hi Kelsey, Thanks a lot for the nice code. I am sure I am doing something wrong because it redirected me back the form (markup) page. It didn't take to me to the page I wanted to redirect to and it didn't show the print screen anymore.

Comment: @Chidi Okeh sounds like you didn't implement the client clicking properly and the `Button` is doing a postback for nothing and that is why you are getting the same page again.  Make sure you are attaching the `doPrint` javascript event correctly to you button (I use the ASP `Buttons` `OnClientClick` event.  Also make sure that you are returning `false` to ensure the postback is aborted as well.

Comment: Sorry good helpers for my mistake earlier. It is actually Kelsey script that works like a charm for me. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: This not work on ipad with chrome. Should use window.onafterprint callback.

Answer (score 8):

For cross browser compatibility, you need to introduce a delay between the window.print() call and the redirect.

I find the following works well (using JQuery framework to print a page as soon as it loaded):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.print();
        setTimeout("closePrintView()", 3000);
    });
    function closePrintView() {
        document.location.href = 'somewhere.html';
    }
</script>
```

This can be easily adapted for "Print" buttons and links etc.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this code :

```
window.print();
window.onafterprint = function(event) {
    window.location.href = 'index.php'
};
```

using  window.print() callBack!!

Comment: On Chrome (newer build on windows) the page redirects before able to print

Comment: This is the one worked best on chrome. Thanks @reza

Answer (score 0):

Redirect on client side using javascript/jQuery

```
  onclick="window.print();window.location.href='results.aspx';"
```

For your case

```
 insub.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "print_form();window.location.href='results.aspx';")
```

Comment: I really must be doing something wrong as every solution you guys have proposed has redirected me to default.aspx which is what I have been referring to as the markup page. None of them is taking me to the page I am trying to redirec to - results.aspx page.

Comment: Post more code, It might help, its very hard to figure out more from that code only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = 'url.aspx';</script>
```

Comment: will this come *after* the print screen? and will not redirect me to default.aspx?

Comment: it's simple javascript redirect, you may want to output it when you need to redirect user somewhere, but don't forget to change `url.aspx` to your location

Comment: Kelsey your good looks very elegant but for some reason, user973254
 seems to be working for me. I want to thank all of you for taking time of your busy schedule to try to assist. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<body onafterprint="openNewPage()"></body>`

```
openNewPage= () => {
    window.location.replace("url");
}
```