# Redirect to another page is causing dup entries

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

dearest experts.

You helped me with this issue on this link below previousl:

[How to I redirect to another page *after* printing document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826209/how-to-i-redirect-to-another-page-after-printing-document)

Things seemed to be working fine until this morning we discussed that users were submitting duplicate entries.

The reason for this is that once the user clicks to Submit their request,they are presented with a button that says, ">>>Click Here To Print Form<<<<".

Users are required to print this form but for some reason, they forget to do so.

In the event that they forget to print this form, they are taking back to the input screen with boxes still retaining the data they initially entered.

Is there a way to redirec them to results.aspx page, whether they print the form or not?

Please see current code and many thanks in advance.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function doPrint() {
        var printContent = document.getElementById("pdmyop");
        window.print(printContent);
        document.location.href = "results.aspx";
    }
</script>

**********************************

<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text=">>>Click Here To Print Form<<<<" OnClientClick="doPrint(); return false;" />
```

Comment: Passing an element to the "print()" method does no good at all; the method always prints the entire document.

Comment: Yes, it is intended to print the entire document. I need help with something more serious though.

Comment: Why you don't call this function after user click Sumbit button?

Comment: This is my submit code. How can I integrate the two? <asp:Button runat="server" ID="insub" Text="OK" Width="100" onclick="SubmitForm" OnClientClick="FreezeScreen('Processing, please wait...');" /> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="icansub" Text="Cancel" Width="100"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this script at the end of the SubmitForm procedure:

```
String script = String.Format("window.print(); window.location = '{0}';", ResolveClientUrl("~/results.aspx"));
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(insub.GetType(), "print", script, true);
```

I hope you can translate this code from C# to VB. If insub placed in an UpdatePanel use ScriptManager instead of the ClientScript.

Be warned, that this code doesn't work in Chrome (as well as any code those make redirect onto different page before document printed)

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuriy. The fact that it won't work with chrome is an issue. They all use chrome, ff and ie. But do I still keep the js, button as indicated in my original post?

Comment: No, with a work-around above you don't need an additional javascript or controls on a page. This script will be executed right after submit procedure executed without any additional effort.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I removed the original javascript that I have and tested your code but there is no print icon. The users would need to print the document as soon as they click the submitform button.