# Doesnot redirect after printing a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I am using the code from another post on Stack Overflow.

[How to I redirect to another page *after* printing document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826209/how-to-i-redirect-to-another-page-after-printing-document)

The page gave me a solution, to write the

```
window.location.href = "";
```

to be written after the `window.print();` method. So I did. Following is the code of mine

```
$('.start-printing').click(function () {
   event.preventDefault();
   window.print();
   var url = window.location.href;
   var formId = url.split('/')[4];
   var newPage = "";
   if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form') {
       newPage = 'form_2';
   } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form') {
       newPage = 'form_2';
   } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form_2') {
       newPage = 'form_3';
   } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form_3') {
       newPage = 'form_4';
   } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form_4') {
       newPage = 'form_5';
   }
   url = url + newPage + formId;
});
```

I am using an anchor tag, to do this job. But I am preventing the default behaviour of it. You can see that in the very first line.

Here is the HTML

```
<a href="~/#startPrinting" class="start-printing">START PRINTING</a>
```

What goes is, that it does allow me to print the document when I click on it. I can see the Chrome's Print popup and I click **Print** button. But after that, it really doesn't redirect me to anywhere.

I have tried watching that in the Console and trying to get to the point, where the problem actually is. But I was not able to find the problem.

I am also making a logic to redirect to the next page of the form depending on the current URL of the page.

What is the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using event.preventDefault(), you're inhibiting the anchor tag from doing what it wants to do naturally, which is hyperlink you to another resource. As a result, you won't be redirected to your desired location.

That said, why not just add some additional Javascript to perform the redirection at the bottom of your click function?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.start-printing').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.print();
        var url = window.location.href;
        var formId = url.split('/')[4];
        var newPage = "";
        if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form') {
            newPage = 'form_2';
        } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form') {
            newPage = 'form_2';
        } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form_2') {
            newPage = 'form_3';
        } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form_3') {
            newPage = 'form_4';
        } else if (url.split('/')[3] == 'form_4') {
            newPage = 'form_5';
        }
        url = url + newPage + formId;
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Even after changing the anchor tag, to a span element. It still doesn't work!

Comment: Try leaving the anchor tag as-is, but simply add the "window.location" code to the very end of your click function. As a result, when the link is clicked, the default behavior is inhibited by event.preventDefault(), which is perfectly fine, the print task then occurs via window.print(). Following this, you begin building the new URL, which should be passed to "window.location".

window.location=url;

Comment: I am trying the same. I have this value, `urlSplit[2] + '/' + newPage + '/' + formId` for the window.location but it doesn't seem to activate. Any guess?