# Printing and Redirecting a PDF Document

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, pdf

I currently am having an issue with a PDF Document that I am required to print and then redirect post print to another page all together.

I have tried among other things

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printandclose(){
        window.print();
        document.location.href = "/wos/addbundle"; 
    }
</script>
```

The problem with this is that the PDF Library doesn't allow this and merely outputs the above code as text.

I am using CodeIgniter and the TCPDF Library to build this.

It's a fairly vague in the question but I hope to find a solution on any of the steps be it html, javascript or php.

So the question is how would I redirect post print? Open a new tab and closing the print page post print is also an option if there is a solution for like windows.close() for example

Answer (score 0):

Something similar has been asked here before, give this a read;

[How to I redirect to another page *after* printing document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826209/how-to-i-redirect-to-another-page-after-printing-document)